# How to extract the first letter and the following three digits from a string using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like

**S103**FYUN031800644100

5**S103**LKAAN031801261400

32**S103**AKJA031804534600

From the above strings, I have to extract the bolded part from each of the above strings using regex, anyone with an idea on how to go about it?

So far I have tried this

```
String acc = "S103L5AN031801261400";
            String regex = ".*S(.{3})";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(acc);
            while(matcher.find()){
                Logger.debug("Match:", matcher.group());
            }
```

But still, I can't get it right.

Comment: What is it about this that isn't right?  That is, how does its result differ from what you want?

Comment: It works only if the first string(S103FYUN031800644100) is tested but it fails on the rest of the strings.

Comment: Like `S[0-9]{3}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex, `[A-Za-z]\\d{3}` which means an alphabet followed by 3 digits.

If you want the substring to start with `S` or `s` only, use `[Ss]\d{3}` or `(?i)s\\d{3}` instead. Note that `(?i)` makes the pattern case-insensitive.

If you want the substring to start with `S` only, use `S\d{3}` instead.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(
                    "S103FYUN031800644100",
                    "5S103LKAAN031801261400",
                    "32S103AKJA031804534600"
                ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + getSubstr(s)));
    }

    static String getSubstr(String s) {
        Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]\\d{3}").matcher(s);
        String substr="";
        if(matcher.find()) {
            substr = matcher.group();
        }
        return substr;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
S103FYUN031800644100 => S103
5S103LKAAN031801261400 => S103
32S103AKJA031804534600 => S103
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tested and it works perfectly as expected.

Comment: @R.Mseti: If it worked out, consider marking this answer as accepted